# Problem with installing Java

Tags: macos, install, java

I just downloaded the latest Java SE Development Kit and tried to install it. The installer opens but then after clicking on install nothing happens. I know this is not very specific (not good with computers).

This is what I saw with command L

```
Oct 25 16:34:45 Dorians-MacBook-Pro installd[483]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----  
Oct 25 16:34:45 Dorians-MacBook-Pro installd[483]: PackageKit: Session UUID file exists - will not overwrite /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/38878AD3-2A7F-4DD3-A00F-FA5955F6CC33.activeSandbox  
Oct 25 16:34:51 Dorians-MacBook-Pro installd[483]: PackageKit: ----- End install -----
```

Comment: Mac Sierra 10.12.6, Java SE Development Kit 8u151 64 ( jdk-8u151-macosx-x64.dmg) I don't know what the difference are between Java Runtime or SDK.

Comment: It's Java SDK didn't know the difference at first.

Comment: JDK - Java Development Kit.  JRE - Java Run-Time Environment.  If you are going to compile and run Java programs, you need the JDK.  If you are just going to execute Java programs, you need the JRE.

Comment: Problem is solved.

Comment: @Dorian Add an answer with the solution to the problem so others who see this question can find it.